# Serializing a dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I have a class named serializableVector2:

```
[Serializable]
class serializableVector2
{
    public float x, y;
    public serializableVector2(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

and I have a struct named savedMapTile:

```
[Serializable]
struct savedMapTile
{
    public oreInstance ore;
    public int backgroundTileId;
    public int playerId;
    public tree tree;
}
```

and I have a dictionary using these two classes:

```
[SerializeField]
Dictionary<serializableVector2, savedMapTile> savedTiles;
```

I am trying to load this dictionary modify it, and then save it again all using serialization.

I am deserializing the dictionary like so:

```
FileStream f = File.Open(saveFileName, FileMode.Open);
BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
savedTiles = (Dictionary<serializableVector2, savedMapTile>)b.Deserialize(f);
f.Close();
```

and I am serializing it like so:

```
FileStream f = File.Open(saveFileName, FileMode.Create);
BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
b.Serialize(f, savedTiles);
f.Close();
```

However, when I try to access an element in the dictionary that I know should exist I get the following error:

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not
>   present in the dictionary.

I get this error from running this code:

```
id = (savedTiles[new serializableVector2(-19,13)].backgroundTileId);
```

What I find really strange is that I am able to print out the entirety of the dictionaries keys and its values as well. This is where I am getting the values -19 and 13 for the Vector2. I print the keys and values like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
{
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log(vv[i].x +" "+vv[i].y);
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log(x[i].backgroundTileId);
}
```

At this point I'm really stumped, I have no clue what is going on. I can see the file being saved in windows explorer, I can access keys and values in the dictionary, but I cant seem to use it properly. It is also important to note that when I use the .Contains() method on the dictionary in a similar way to how I am trying to access a value, it always returns false.

This is for a Unity 5 project, using C# in visual studio running on windows 8.1.

Comment: Among other things, your `FileStream` instances need to be in `using` blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `serializableVector2` from a `class` to a `struct` and you should be able to find things in your dictionary.  Someone may correct me if I have this wrong, but to the best of my knowledge the `Dictionary` is going to call `GetHashCode` on the key and use that code to store the item in the dictionary.  If you create two instances of your class with the same x and y coordinates and call `GetHashCode` you will see that two instances yield different hash codes.  If you change it to a `struct` than they will produce the same hash code.  I believe this is what is causing you to get the "Key not found" issues.  On a somewhat related note, it does seem strange that the constructor takes `int` for the x and y and then stores them as floats.  You may want to consider changing the constructor to take `float`.

```
[Serializable]
struct serializableVector2
{
    public float x, y;
    public serializableVector2(float x, float y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't rely on floating point equality. Dictionary relies on GetHashCode and Equals, both of which will give different results if the any of the corresponding floating point values are even slightly different from each other.

Comment: @Huacanacha - Thanks. I forgot the Equals part, which makes sense for "Contains" as well as collision handling.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues:

1. Your dictionary key `serializableVector2` is a class relying on the default equality and hashing methods. The defaults use reference equality such that only variables pointing to the same object will be equal and return the same hash.
2. If that were not the case you would still be relying on floating point equality. Unless your serialised can guarantee precise storage and retrieval of floating point values the deserialised `serializableVector2` may NOT be equal to the original.

Suggested solution:

Override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` for your `serializableVector2` class. When performing comparisons and hashing round your floats to  within 32-bit floating point precision of your expected range of values. You can rely on 6+ significant digits of precision (within the same range) so if your world is += 1000 units I believe you can safely round to 3 decimal points.

Example for GetHashCode (without testing):

```
public override int GetHashCode() {
    return Math.Round(x,3).GetHashCode() ^ Math.Round(y,3).GetHashCode();
}
```